# .htaccess Clean URL With a Twist

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a URL like this: /pages/join.php that I need to rewrite via .htaccess to this: /join

I'm doing that just fine with the following:

```
RewriteRule ^join$ /pages/join.php [L]
```

But I also want to make sure that if the user or spider tries to access /pages/join.php directly, it will be forced to: /join   So nobody should ever see /pages/join.php in their browser. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED (AGAIN):**

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/join$
RewriteRule .* /join.php?_internal [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !_internal
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /join.php
RewriteRule .* /page_not_found.php [L]
```

Another (more secure) option would be to add this to the top of your join.php file:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/join.php') die('NO DIRECT ACCESS!');
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It forces the URL to change, but the page doesn't load. The file itself is located at: /pages/join.php

Also, I only want this to work on the join page, not all pages in the pages folder.

Comment: Doesn't work. Error: "Page redirecting improperly". I'm guessing you can't create a redirect loop like that.